# add asynchronous capabilities to django

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, websocket

I have a mature, production django-tastypie server with an angular client service where I need to update the client with real-time data. I was thinking about websockets for the client.
my question is which strategy is best for the server side:

1. use some django [plugin](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-websocket-request) that handles asynchronism
2. raise a new tornado server for the sake of handling the async part (and then make it learn my django users/authentication model)
3. embed tornado inside django (like [this](https://github.com/bdarnell/django-tornado-demo))

what is your recommendation? or maybe something else I didn't think of?

Comment: Not sure about the tornado part, but the best async task manager that I khow of for django is celery https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery using which you can define pretty much any task. A great tutorial to implement it is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7yCmAhthkMk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using this:

https://github.com/jrief/django-websocket-redis

I have used it in production and it works very well; the main benefit is that it is non-blocking and integrates with Django's auth system (you can message specific users, groups or all users via the websocket).

@Randi's suggestion to use Celery if you need to run async tasks is a very good one: Celery is excellent. Combine that with django-websocket-redis and you can perform long-running async tasks and give your users real-time updates as the task runs.

An alternative, but probably less appropriate solution would be to poll the server for changes/notifications from your angular client every 2-5 seconds. However, this is the "old school" approach and will potentially add A LOT of load to your server. This approach would save the overhead of managing extra services and would probably be better choice if you have a small number of users.